# Can't Capture Screenshots Of Webpages Using Firefox's CLI After Upgrade To Firefox 54.0

Tags: 16.04, command-line, firefox, screenshot

I've been using the Firefox Command Line Interface (Shift + F2) to take fullpage screenshots in Firefox for several months now.

Below is the syntax I use to capture screenshots via Firefox's CLI:

```
screenshot --fullpage filename.png
```

However, upon upgrade to Firefox 54.0, anytime I attempt to take a screenshot of a webpage it now returns with "unknownError" almost every time. On a few occasions, I've gotten the error "TypeError: this.target.tab is null" instead.

I've tried taking screenshots of dozens of different webpages both with and without the --fullpage parameter with no success. In fact, the only screenshots I've been able to capture are of Firefox's "New Tab" page and other Firefox pages, such as "about:config."

I'd greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same here. But even the about:config page screenshot is limited to the visible area.

Comment: On one laptop, I have Firefox 54 direct from Mozilla. On that, the screenshot doesn't work. On another laptop, which has the version supplied by the Ubuntu repos, it works fine.

Comment: I'm using the version supplied by Ubuntu. AFAIK the only difference is the Ubuntu Modifications extension, which I've had disabled for years.

Comment: I also managed to find a bug report regarding this issue on bugzilla, indicating it was present in 53.0 as well. However, it worked fine for me in FF 53.0. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1361110

Comment: I'm having the opposite problem: the CLI will still take a screenshot fine, *if I can open the CLI in the first place*. Most of the time I press Shift and F2 and nothing happens. Occasionally it deigns to open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems things may have changed... This is what I did:

First select Tools > Web Developer > Inspector.

Look for the little cog-wheel with `Toolbox options` as its tooltip. Click on the cog-wheel to open the Toolbox options.

Scroll down to Available Toolbox Buttons and look for "Take a screenshot of the entire page". Check its box. A little camera icon should now appear to the left of the Toolbox options cog-wheel. If you don't see it, close the Inspector window and reopen it.

[image: Firefox full page screenshot]

Comment: Nice find! I know they've been developing a more fully featured screenshot tool for some time, planned for a later release.

Comment: I managed to find a way to enable the feature in about:config by changing "extensions.screenshots.system-disabled" to "false." A "Take A Screenshot" button will appear in the upper right hand corner of the browser.

Comment: However, I like your solution better, as it's quicker and doesn't entail automatically uploading all screenshots to FF servers. Hopefully the CLI screenshot feature isn't being deprecated, as I like being able to set my own filenames.

Comment: @PC_LOAD_LETTER : I do not see "extensions.screenshots.system-disabled" in about:config in my version of Firefox. I posted a separate question to address that at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065359/how-to-enable-firefox-screenshots-button-on-firefox-61-0-1-on-ubuntu-18-04