# How to enable Firefox Screenshots button on Firefox 61.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firefox, screenshot

What do I need to do in order to enable FireFox Screenshots in my version of Firefox, so that I do not have to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> command line to generate a full page screenshot?

The dropdown on my version of Firefox shows:

[image: dropdown]

According to [a comment on another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925551/cant-capture-screenshots-of-webpages-using-firefoxs-cli-after-upgrade-to-firef#comment1469970_925952%20comment), I should be able to enable the Firefox Screenshots button, but when I go to `about:config` and type in `about:config extensions.screenshots` I see that is should be active:

[image: about:config e3xtensions.screenshots]

I am able to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type

```
screenshot ~/foo.png --fullpage
```

as a workaround, but that is cumbersome for a operation I plan to use frequently, that is, once it is working.

Update: The **Customize...** area does not show anything obvious that I can use to drag and drop:

[image: Customize...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open a webpage and click the three dots icon ("Page actions") in the address bar.
2. You should see a "Take a Screenshot" icon. Right click on it.
3. Select "Add to Address Bar".

Comment: The "Take a Screenshot" option is not there. I guess it's not supported in Linux?

Comment: If you're asking whether the feature does not work on *any* Linux *at all*, then the simple answer is "no, that's not correct".

Comment: thanks for your reply, you're right of course, I just checked on another Linux machine and the option is there. Must be something about this particular build somehow!